# Get all series values when click on single line chart

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

```
 <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
 <div id="container_dialogue" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

    var chart1;
 function test(name, e){
alert(name);

$( "#container_dialogue").empty();
$( "#container_dialogue").dialog({height: 500,modal: true});

$( "#container_dialogue").append("<div id='dialogue_inner'></div><div            id='dialogue_inner1'></div>");
 $("#dialogue_inner1").append(name);

 /**
  on Clicking any chart based on this property or 'e' i need to identify       the              corresponsing series and to display in dialogue box.
     As of now i hard coded the values and displays a single chart only 

   **/
  $('#dialogue_inner').highcharts({

    title: {
        text: 'Energy Consumption'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Energy'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: name,
        data: [1,0,4,5,6,9,3] //hardcoded values
    }]
});

 }


  $(function () { 
  chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line'
    },

title: {
        text: 'Energy Consumption'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Energy'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
            line: {
                   events:{
                          click: function(e){
                    var name = this.name;

                    alert(this.name);
                                 test(name, e);
                          }    
                   }
            }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'A',
        data: [2,3,8,1,9,6,4,8]
    }, {
        name: 'B',
        data: [5,6,3,8,4,1,6,0]
    },{
        name: 'C',
        data: [1,5,4,3,7,7,2,6]
    },{
        name: 'D',
        data: [9,10,2,4,5,8,3,8]
    }]
    });    

   });
```

on Clicking any line chart based on this property or 'e' i need to identify the corresponsing series and display that particular chart in dialogue box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [series click](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.click) and then print all points

http://jsfiddle.net/6gYLX/3/

```
 click: function() {
                    console.log(this);
                        var series = this.data;

                    $.each(series,function(i,point){
                        console.log(point.y);
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, i tried your code and am getting the values too on alert one by one.. but i need the complete series points together and plot a line with those values in dialogue box. Could you please help me?

Comment: in the funcion test(name, e) i need to pass name of the series and series points..